# join two table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two table entity channel and channel_stats.I want to save data in tables using session.save().
channel_stats can contain duplicate entry with duplicate channel ID.

Can you please tell me how to do so using secondary table annotation in hibernate. or is there any other way? i tried with embedded and embedded annotation bit looks like its for same table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="channel_list")
public class Channel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="channel_youtubeID")
private String channelYoutubeID;

@Column(name="channel_title")
private String channelTitle;

@Column(name="thumbnail_url")
private String thumbnailUrl;

@Column(name="active_bit")
private int activeBit;

@Embedded
private ChannelStats channelStats;


public Channel() {

}


public Channel(String channelYoutubeID, String channelTitle, String thumbnailUrl, int activeBit,
        ChannelStats channelStats) {
    super();
    this.channelYoutubeID = channelYoutubeID;
    this.channelTitle = channelTitle;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    this.activeBit = activeBit;
    this.channelStats = channelStats;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getChannelYoutubeID() {
    return channelYoutubeID;
}


public void setChannelYoutubeID(String channelYoutubeID) {
    this.channelYoutubeID = channelYoutubeID;
}


public String getChannelTitle() {
    return channelTitle;
}


public void setChannelTitle(String channelTitle) {
    this.channelTitle = channelTitle;
}


public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}


public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}


public int getActiveBit() {
    return activeBit;
}


public void setActiveBit(int activeBit) {
    this.activeBit = activeBit;
}


public ChannelStats getChannelStats() {
    return channelStats;
}


public void setChannelStats(ChannelStats channelStats) {
    this.channelStats = channelStats;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Channel [id=" + id + ", channelYoutubeID=" + channelYoutubeID + ", channelTitle=" + channelTitle
            + ", thumbnailUrl=" + thumbnailUrl + ", activeBit=" + activeBit + ", channelStats=" + channelStats
            + "]";
}
```

}

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name="channel_stats")
public class ChannelStats {

@Column(name="channelID")
private String channelID;

@Column(name="viewCount")
private long viewCount;

@Column(name="commentCount")
private long commentCount;

@Column(name="subscriberCount")
private long subscriberCount;

@Column(name="hiddenSubscriberCount")
private boolean hiddenSubscriberCount;

@Column(name="videoCount")
private long videoCount;


public ChannelStats() {

}


public ChannelStats(String channelID, long viewCount, long commentCount, long subscriberCount,
        boolean hiddenSubscriberCount, long videoCount) {
    super();
    this.channelID = channelID;
    this.viewCount = viewCount;
    this.commentCount = commentCount;
    this.subscriberCount = subscriberCount;
    this.hiddenSubscriberCount = hiddenSubscriberCount;
    this.videoCount = videoCount;
}


public String getChannelID() {
    return channelID;
}


public void setChannelID(String channelID) {
    this.channelID = channelID;
}


public long getViewCount() {
    return viewCount;
}


public void setViewCount(long viewCount) {
    this.viewCount = viewCount;
}


public long getCommentCount() {
    return commentCount;
}


public void setCommentCount(long commentCount) {
    this.commentCount = commentCount;
}


public long getSubscriberCount() {
    return subscriberCount;
}


public void setSubscriberCount(long subscriberCount) {
    this.subscriberCount = subscriberCount;
}


public boolean isHiddenSubscriberCount() {
    return hiddenSubscriberCount;
}


public void setHiddenSubscriberCount(boolean hiddenSubscriberCount) {
    this.hiddenSubscriberCount = hiddenSubscriberCount;
}


public long getVideoCount() {
    return videoCount;
}


public void setVideoCount(long videoCount) {
    this.videoCount = videoCount;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ChannelStats [channelID=" + channelID + ", viewCount=" + viewCount + ", commentCount=" + commentCount
            + ", subscriberCount=" + subscriberCount + ", hiddenSubscriberCount=" + hiddenSubscriberCount
            + ", videoCount=" + videoCount + "]";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, `@Embeddable` is not what you want in this case. `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` is used when you don't want a separate second table. Since you want a separate table to have the `ChannelStat` data, it seems like you are trying to create a `@OneToMany` relationship where one `Channel` object can have multiple `ChannelStat` objects.

So your `Channel` class should have

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "channel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
private List<ChannelStat> channelStat;
```

Instead of

```
@Embedded
private ChannelStats channelStats;
```

And your `ChannelStat` class should have

```
public class ChannelStats {

    // Other variables and their getters and setters

    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn( name = "id" )
    private Channel channel;
}
```

Read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) for more information.